# QML SwipeView is covering entire window

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I am having some problems if i use swipe view and i have written following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Swipe View")

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill:parent

        Rectangle{
            id:rightRect
            anchors.right:parent.right
            width: parent.width*0.50
            height:parent.height
            color:"yellow"
        }

        Rectangle{
            id:leftRect
            width:parent.width*0.50
            height:parent.height
            color:"lightgreen"
            border.color:"red"
            anchors.right:rightRect.left
            SwipeView{
                id:swipeView
                anchors.fill : leftRect
                //Layout.fillWidth: true
                currentIndex: 0
                interactive: false
                Page{
                    id:page1

                    Rectangle{
                        width:parent.width
                        height:parent.height
                        color:"lightgreen"
                        Button{
                            text:"move to 2"
                            onClicked: swipeView.currentIndex = 1
                        }
                    }
                }

                Page{
                    id:page2
                    Rectangle{
                        width:parent.width
                        height:parent.height
                        color:"lightblue"
                        Button{
                            text:"move to 1"
                            onClicked: swipeView.currentIndex = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the screen shots:

1) Initially i have set current index to **"0"** but index "1" blue area is visible and it's covering the right area(Yellow rectangle):

[image]

2) if I click on **move to 2 button** then the yellow rect is visible as expected.

[image]

Now, Even if I click on **move to 1 button** I need same behavior ie., yellow rect should be visible all the time.How to achieve this ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `clip:true` to the parent of your SwipeView and it will be good.

```
Rectangle{
            id:leftRect
            width:parent.width*0.50
            height:parent.height
            color:"lightgreen"
            border.color:"red"
            anchors.right:rightRect.left
            clip:true    //add this
            SwipeView{
```

According to [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop)

> If clipping is enabled, an item will clip its own painting, as well as
>   the painting of its children, to its bounding rectangle.

By default this value is false hence your `SwipeView` goes out of the rectangle area.

Comment: If I add clip it is working as expected, But is there any way to disable transition when the index is changed ??

Comment: Which index are you referring to?

Comment: SwipeView ->  when i set this **swipeView.currentIndex** there is some transition/animation happening .

Comment: I believe your problem is listed on Qt forum: https://forum.qt.io/topic/81535/swipeview-page-change-without-animation

Unfortunately there is no way to do this using only SwipeView as mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Thanks and I have already referred above link, Hope will get an option in the next version.

Comment: @pra7 Take a look at [`StackLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html) that does the same thing as `SwipeView`but without animation when you change the `currentIndex`.

Comment: @Blabdouze .. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try StackLayout.